# How to access a list property of an object using thymleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

How can I access a list variable contained inside the object in HTML using Thymleaf

Eg :All the aClient properties are String objects.They can be accessed as

```
<tr th:each="aClient : ${clientList}">
 <td th:text="${aClient.firstName}"/>
 <td th:text="${aClient.lastName}"/>
 <td th:text="${aClient.address}"/>
 <td th:text="${aClient.clientType}"/>
```

But for property like

`List<Service> services`.

How can I access it?

Tried doing below after some reading. But it did not pick up the names of services.

```
<div th:each="service, serv : *{services}">
<input type="text" th:field="*{service[__${serv.index}__].name}" />
</div>
```

"name" is the property in Service class with getters and setters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to insert the serivce names in the column.This is achieved by

```
<td>
    <div th:each="service : ${aClient.services}" th:text="${service.name}"></div> 
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The contents of an input field are identified by the `value` attribute.

Also, you don't need to use the Thymeleaf `serv` iterator tracker, since in this case, you are already iterating each `Service` object - and you just want to get the value of each object's `name` field.

This can all be simplified to the following:

```html
<div th:each="service : ${services}">
    <input type="text" th:value="${service.name}" />
</div>
```

(It's basically the same approach as you used for your `th:text` data.)

The generated HTML is as follows:

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" value="service 1 name">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" value="service 2 name">
</div>
```

This assumes you want each input field in its own div.